# How to customize auth0 Lock login UI?

Tags: angularjs, locking, auth0

I am trying to customize my login screen in auth0 lock, to change logo, i placed below code. and its working fine.

```
      theme: {     
        logo: 'https://example.com/logo58px.png'
      },
      languageDictionary: { title: 'Custom title here' }
```

its not working,

But I wanted to change text auth0 to my app name, How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real easy way to go about this. All of the settings for Auth0 Lock are available to you though. In `lock.js` you'll find all available settings you need.

For example, if you want to change the `title`, open `lock.js` in your favorite text editor and `CTRL+F` for "Auth0" (include the quotes") and you'll find what it is you need.

In my version of lock it's in an object that looks like this:

```
exports.default = {
    ...
    title: "Auth0",
    ...
}
```

If you're looking to change the UI as in CSS-rules, simply inspect the Auth0 Lock in the browser, look for a specific class on the object you'd like to change and set your own rules to it.

It's not that much of a hassle in terms of "reverse engineering" (Loosely using that term here) but you can virtually change anything you want about the Auth0 Lock.

Just don't forget to include it in your repo.

Answer (score 1):

While @Tom Nijs's answer does fix your problem, it is not good practise to change the source code of the library that you are using. An example where you could lose your modified code is when you update the Auth0 Lock library. Keeping track of all these pieces of modified code between different versions of libraries is a real hassle.

Instead, I would suggest to do the following:

The Auth0 Lock exposes the `languageDictionary` property in the settings property.

So to continue with your provided code snippet, you could do this in the lock's settings:

```
`theme: {
    logo: 'https://example.com/logo58px.png'
},
languageDictionary: {
    title: 'Custom title here',
    forgotPasswordAction: 'Custom lost password phrase here'
}`
```

If you are looking to customise more properties/text, you can just add them to the `languageDictionary` object, all the possible properties can be found here => https://github.com/auth0/lock/blob/master/src/i18n/en.js

The property names depend on the Auth0 Lock version, above configuration is for Auth0 Lock 10.0.0+
Property names of earlier lock versions are also still available in Auth0's documentation.

Comment: mine is 10.13.0, and its not working, any thing i need to add?

Comment: What are your Lock settings now?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Auth0's new universal login and customize it.
I've created a [full tutorial for this](https://dev.to/permit_io/a-guide-for-an-awesome-custom-auth0-universal-login-100h)